# Python how to detect if a thread join timed out

Tags: python

I have a program that starts a couple of worker threads. The main thread contains `t.join(TIMEOUT)` where `TIMEOUT` equals some integer like 5.

How can I detect if a thread joined due to a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention of `t.join(5)` is for your main thread to wait up to `5` seconds for your worker thread `t` to finish naturally.

So, if the timeout expires, that means the thread didn't finish during that time. In other words the thread will still be alive and running after the join operation - which you can detect using `t.isAlive()`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects